# How to create context menu on right click of DropDownList item?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an `asp:DropDownList` that I populate from a database. I want to be able to right click on any one of the items and *delete* or *edit* the item by showing a context menu with those options for the item. Any ideas on how to do this or if it’s possible?

Comment: `asp:DropDownList` creates a `<select>` which is handled entirely by the browser.  What you're asking will not be possible using this mechanism.  You will have to simulate your own drop down list which you will have full control over and can then add a context menu and add/remove items easily.  You might like to start with an existing plugin rather than start from scratch.

Comment: could use a KeyDown event handler to delete or edit the selected item in the dropdown instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @freedomn-m points out, you need to make your own dropdown list.

For example you could do something like the following:

Add some **html** to hold the dropdown:

```
<button id='dog_button'>Dogs</button>
<div id='hold'></div>
```

Add some **CSS** for styling:

```
body {
  font-family: arial; 
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none; 
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: gold; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}

.show {
  width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #dedede;
  padding: 10px;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ops {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Use **jQuery** to populate dropdown, and add IDs as needed. Use **sweet alert** to handle pop-up options when **right clicking your select option**:

```
categories_and_ops = {
    'Dog Beds' : ['Soft Dog Beds','Matress Dog Beds','Plastic Dog Beds','3 Peaks','Dog Blankets','Heating Dog Beds', 'Specific Dog Beds', 'Luxury Dog Beds'],
    'Dog Coats' : ['...','...','...','...','...','...', '...', '...']
}

$('#dog_button').click(function() {
$.each(categories_and_ops, function(cat, op) {
  div_id = 'div_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  $('#hold').append("<div class='show' id=" + div_id + "></div><br>")
  $('#' + div_id).append("<span style='color:orange; font-weight: bold'>" + cat + "</span><div class='square'>-</div><br>" + '<br>') 
  op.forEach(function(op_elem) { 
  op_id = 'op_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000); $('#' + div_id).append('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + "<span id=" + op_id + " class='ops'>" + op_elem + "</span>" + '<br><br>');
  $('#' + op_id).contextmenu(function() { delete_edit(); return false;    });
  })
  })
  })

$(document).on('mouseover', '.ops', function() { $(this).css('background', 'grey') })
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.ops', function() { $(this).css('background', '#dedede') })

$(document).on('click', '.square', function() {
if($(this).html() == '-') {
  $(this).parent().children('.ops').toggle();
  $(this).html('+');
  } else {
  $(this).parent().children('.ops').toggle();
  $(this).html('-');
  }
  })

function delete_edit() {
    swal({
    html: "<button id='del_button'>DELETE</button><br><br><button id='edit_button'>EDIT</button>",
    showConfirmButton : false
    }).catch(swal.noop)
    }

$(document).on('click', '#del_button', function() {
    alert('DELETED!')
})

$(document).on('click', '#edit_button', function() {
    alert('ADD YOUR EDIT CODE!')
})
```

**Result**:

[image]

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/CyberneticSean/f274fopm/2/#&togetherjs=xxzEjDwV73)

Comment: Very intuitive and complete answer, thanks! I will go try this, as for now, I’ll mark this as the answer